# Can I safely charge&use my macbook with the adaptor below?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging, hdmi, ethernet

I need to use an Ethernet cable, VGA monitor, usb connection and power cable in same time with my macbook. That's why i need an adapter because my macbook has only one usb-c port.

Let me share a *technical specifications* for the Adapter:

- Compatible with devices using the port-Type C.
- Data Transfer high-speed 5Gbps: provides you with a fast transfer, you can save time.
- Multifunctional design: Type-C to HDMI, USB 3.0 and VGA, USB-C,
- 1000Mbps Gigabit Ethernet.
- Type: Adapter
- Interface: VGA,Type-C USB3.0,USB 3.0 ,network port
- Output Voltage: 5 - 20V
- Output Current: 0 - 3.5A  DC Port: 3.5 x 1.1
- Brand : Xiaomi
- Model : ZJQ04TM

**So I have two questions:**

1. Can this adapter charge macbook?
2. Safe to charge the macbook with this adapter?

[Technical Specifications for my macbook (macbook retina, 12 inch, 2017)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP757?locale=en_EN)

Answer (score 1):

In general it is safe to attach standards compliant USB Type-C products to the MacBook.

If the multi-adapter offers power delivery (i.e. charging) and is standards compliant, it should be perfectly safe to use. According to the documentation it should offer charging at up to 65W which is plenty for the MacBook.

I have however not tested this specific adapter with the MacBook.